# Error in adding image to Salesforce static resource using Mule4

Tags: salesforce, mulesoft, salesforce-lightning, mule-component, mule4

I have to add images to Salesforce static resources via mule integration. I'm using Salesforce create connector. I'm getting those images from the HTTP listener as multipart/form-data. I get the image out from it and tried to update it in the salesforce static resource as application/octet-stream.

```
 output application/octet-stream
    ---
    payload.parts.image.content
```

But I'm getting an error message as (error.description)

```
""Cannot coerce Binary { encoding: UTF-8, mediaType: application/octet-stream; charset=UTF-8, mimeType: application/octet-stream, raw: org.mule.weave.v2.el.SeekableCursorStream@54ca576e, contentLength: 6039 } ("/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wCEAAoHCBYVFRgVFRYYGBgaGRgcGhwZGRgcGRocGhgaGhoh...) to Array" evaluating expression: "payload"."
```

Console log

```
Message               : "Cannot coerce Binary { encoding: UTF-8, mediaType: application/octet-stream; charset=UTF-8, mimeType: application/octet-stream, raw: org.mule.weave.v2.el.SeekableCursorStream@54ca576e, contentLength: 6039 } ("/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wCEAAoHCBYVFRgVFRYYGBgaGRgcGhwZGRgcGRocGhgaGhoh...) to Array" evaluating expression: "payload".
Element               : googledriveimageuploaderFlow/processors/4 @ googledriveimageuploader:googledriveimageuploader.xml:49 (Create)
Element DSL           : <salesforce:create type="StaticResource" doc:name="Create" doc:id="e2c59345-e6b8-4e85-85a9-5ec698ba6676" config-ref="Salesforce_Config"></salesforce:create>
Error type            : MULE:EXPRESSION
FlowStack             : at googledriveimageuploaderFlow(googledriveimageuploaderFlow/processors/4 @ googledriveimageuploader:googledriveimageuploader.xml:49 (Create))
```

salesforce create connector xml

```
<salesforce:create type="StaticResource" doc:name="Create" doc:id="e2c5927e-e6b8-4e34-85a9-567c698ba6676" config-ref="Salesforce_Config">
        </salesforce:create>
```

Saleforce connector vertion is 10.12.4

Above away is working for saving the image in local drive and google drive but not for salesforce static resource. Can some one point me how do imege update in salesforce static resource?

Comment: Is that the complete error message? It look like something is missing. Also share the Salesforce connector operation as XML and version.

Comment: @aled I added error. description and XML. I tried updating the metadata connector too but still the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Usually Salesforce APIs expect binary files to be encoded with base64. You can use DataWeave [base64()](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.4/dataweave-cookbook-decode-encode) function. In this particular case you need to respect the format expected by the Salesforce API. You need to send an array and each element has to have the expected metadata information.

Example:

```
%dw 2.0
import * from dw::core::Binaries
output application/java
---
[{
    Title: "MyImage",
    PathOnClient : "myimage.jpg",
    VersionData: toBase64(payload.parts.image.content)
}]
```

Source: https://help.mulesoft.com/s/article/How-to-create-a-file-in-salesforce-using-salesforce-connector

Comment: I used this method but still same error message:  ""Cannot coerce Binary { class: org.mule.runtime.core.internal.streaming.bytes.ManagedCursorStreamProvider } ("Ii85ai80QUFRU2taSlJnQUJBUUFBQVFBQkFBRC8yd0NFQUFvSENCWVZGUmdWRlJZWUdCZ2FHUmdj...) to Array" evaluating expression: "payload

Comment: I missed a part of the error. I have updated my answer with a correct example.

Comment: Thanks for your support. I did those changes. I'm not getting any error now but still, the image is not displaying in Static resources. Do you have any idea? I got the status code as 200, not 201

Comment: Found the exception. Though it returns 200, while debugging in logger after create connector, adding data operation failed due to invalid body. Looks like base64() does not work here.